# Xpath in Selenium (chromedriver) wont match second tag

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to match a specific span on a website with selenium chromedriver (Version 79.0.3945.36 for Chrome 79) in java. The span heavily nested, but by itself simply:

```
    <span id="nodeval" title="Target XYZ ">Target XYZ </span>
```

I can successfully use `text()` or `contains`, but i would like to match the `@title` - if possible using `starts-with` (due to end changeing dynamically) but this i cannot get it to work correctly, even with just direct tag matching. Here is my test code test with contains, text, direct title and title using starts-with.

```
    String in_strChapterName = "Target XYZ ";
    List<WebElement> print = myDownloader.getWebDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//span[starts-with(@title,'"+in_strChapterName+"')]"));
    List<WebElement> print2 = myDownloader.getWebDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'" + in_strChapterName + "')]"));        
    List<WebElement> print3 = myDownloader.getWebDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//span[text()='" + in_strChapterName + "']"));        
    List<WebElement> print4 = myDownloader.getWebDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//span[@title='"+in_strChapterName+"']"));

    System.out.println("contains matches: "+print2.size());  //1 matches        
    System.out.println("text matches "+print3.size());       //1 matches

    System.out.println("starts-with title matches: "+print.size());  //0 matches
    System.out.println("direct title matches: "+print4.size());      //0 matches
```

Since i use example code (from here: https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html) almost 1:1 - only the tag isn't the first tag of the span - i wonder why the tag selection does not work for me...

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem in XSLT-1.0 and the result was that all four expressions are working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

To match the *title* you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
String in_strChapterName = "Target XYZ";
List<WebElement> print4 = myDownloader.getWebDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(@title, '" +in_strChapterName+ "')]"));
System.out.println("direct title matches: "+print4.size()); //1 match
```